# GSP use set variable as counter

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a problem using a variable from a webflow as a counter

I tried several possibilities

```
 <g:set var="count" value="${flow.ipcount  as Integer}" />
                 <g:each in="${ (1..'${count}' ) }">
```

and

```
<g:set var="count" value="${flow.ipcount}" />
                 <g:each in="${ (1..'${count}' ) }">
```

But I get only an error: Message:java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the inner `${}`:

```
<g:each in="${ (1..count) }">
```